# TableView#scrollTo(int index) but show row in bottom

Tags: scroll, javafx, tableview

I would like to scroll down to a specific row in a `TableView`. `TableView#scrollTo(int index)` puts the row on the specified index in the top of the view, but I would like the specified index to be in the bottom of the view. This is because the specified row will always be the row below the currently focused row for me, and I just want to scroll as much as needed to show that next row. I.e: I want the behaviour you get when you change the row selection by using the UP and DOWN keys. Is this possible? Here's an MCVE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestScrollToTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        ObservableList<String> columns = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            columns.add("column " + i);
        }

        ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 100; rowIndex++) {
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.size(); colIndex++) {
                row.add("row" + rowIndex + "col" + colIndex);
            }
            data.add(row);
        }

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.size(); colIndex++) {
            final int j = colIndex;
            TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> col = new TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>(
                    columns.get(colIndex));
            col.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j)));

            table.getColumns().add(col);
        }

        table.setItems(data);

        Button scrollToButton = new Button("Focus next row");
        scrollToButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (table.getFocusModel().getFocusedItem() != null) {
                int nextIndex = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedIndex()+1;
                table.getFocusModel().focus(nextIndex);
                table.scrollTo(nextIndex);
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(table, scrollToButton);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function

```
private void scrollToUpAndBottom(int indexToScroll, VirtualFlow vf) {//scroll to up
    if (indexToScroll < vf.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex()) {
        TableView.this.scrollTo(indexToScroll);
    } else if (indexToScroll > vf.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex()) {//scroll to down
        int delta = vf.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex() - vf.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex();
        TableView.this.scrollTo(indexToScroll - delta + 2); // +2 is  margin
    }
}
```

to get virtualFlow from TableView, you can use TableViewSkin which has a protected  attribute "flow" so you have to create your own skin which make this attribute pulic

```
public VirtualFlow getVirtualFlow(){ return flow;}
```